# How to move a rectangle every 5 second in javascript cavas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, timer

I need to move a rectangle in a random position every 5 seconds, I have this

```
function rectangle(x,y){
var ctx
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 15, 10);
ctx.stroke();
}
function randomMove(){
var myVar;
var x;
var y;
myVar = setInterval( , 5000);
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
rectangle(x,y)
}
```

I don't know what to add in the setInterval next to the 5000, what should I add to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the function you want to execute every 5 seconds, as your function has parameters you have to pass it within anonymous func

```
 function rectangle(x,y){
    var ctx
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20, 20, 15, 10);
    ctx.stroke();
    }
    function randomMove(){
    var myVar;
    var x;
    var y;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    myVar = setInterval( ()=> {rectangle(x,y)}, 5000); // pass the rectangle function
    }
```